# How to turn the results fetched from database into a single string?

Tags: java

I have the code that fetches tags from the database:

```
public void fetchTags() {  
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();  
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(TagsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,  
                 new String[]{Tags.COLUMN_TNAME}, null, null, null);  
        cursor.getCount();  
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {  
            System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tags.COLUMN_TNAME)));         
        }  
        cursor.close();         
    }
```

Output:

[image]

How can I turn the results into one single string, where the characters are separated by comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
// ...

final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String prefix = "";

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {  
    builder.append(prefix);
    prefix = SEPARATOR;
    builder.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tags.COLUMN_TNAME)));    
}  

String output = builder.toString()

// ...
```

A `StringBuilder` allows you to concatenate `String`s faster that the normal `outputString += inputString` would do. This has to do with the fact that `String` objects are immutable, while a `StringBuilder` isn't. If you want to know more about that, have a look e.g. at [this article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder.html).

**Edit:** To return the created String to the calling method, your method `fetchTags()` has to be defined like this:

```
public String fetchTags() {

    // your code

    return output;

}
```

You defined it with return type `void`: `public void fetchTags() { ... }`. This will not allow you to return any values.

**The complete method `fetchTags()`** should look like this:

```
public String fetchTags() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(TagsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
            Tags.COLUMN_TNAME
        }, null, null, null);
    cursor.getCount();

    final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        builder.append(prefix);
        prefix = SEPARATOR;
        builder.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tags.COLUMN_TNAME)));
    }

    String output = builder.toString()

    cursor.close();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Does that mean the output I get from it doesn't count as a String? But I also want to use it as one single string in another class, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, of course. `String output = builder.toString()` will write the content as a normal `String` into `output`. You can use that like any other `String`.

Comment: But outside this method in another, it won't recognize "builder" right? Like I have a String "mSearchTerm",  in another method I wanted the output of fetchTags() to be this String, how should I call fetchTags() there?

Comment: If you put the code about into your method `fetchTags()`, you have to `return` the `output` string: `return output;`. Then you can use the returned value in the calling method: `String tag = fetchTags();`

Answer (score 1):

You could accumulate the results in a `StringBuilder` before printing them:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// Special cases: empty cursor and cursor with a single result
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    builder.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tags.COLUMN_TNAME)));
}

// Other cases
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    builder.append(',')
           .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tags.COLUMN_TNAME)));
}

System.out.println(builder);
```